# "Do not Disturb" doesn't block anything

Tags: samsung, do-not-disturb

I have a Samsung Galaxy A71 5G. When I got the phone I setup the "Do not Disturb" on a schedule. It worked fine.

At some point I let the phone install updates. Ever since then, as far as I can tell "Do not Disturb" does not block anything. It automatically comes on on the same schedule. But nothing is blocked. Every single app, phone call, & text message still comes through. I do not have any exceptions in my "Do not Disturb" configuration screen.

What do I need to do in order to get "Do not Disturb" working again?